# Is it possible to template JIRA issues with pre-filled field contents?

Tags: templating, jira

In first place I look for default JIRA functionality e.g. without 3rd party plugins to simlify and improve the issue workflow.

Examples:

- Simple: Template for an acceptable bug report
- Probably, less simple: Set specific keywords if issue is created by a specific user e.g. "ops" for issues created by myself because I am currently in an Ops team. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to get far without any plugins. What you can take a look at is the *Default Values for 'Create Issue' screen* plugin. We were using it in the past, however gave up because defaults could be set only per issue type, and no other conditions. I was in contact with the supplier, though, and they confirmed that defaults per user and other extensions were on their roadmap. Makes sense to check if they are already available.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this using the Automation for JIRA if you are a Project Admin.

Less simple one - Maybe something like

1. When new issue is created
2. Check if condition for specific users
3. Edit the issue and set certain fields to desired values